# In Sequelize, How do you perform a where query on an association inside of an $or statement?

Tags: associations, sequelize.js

I have three models, User, Project and ProjectMember. Keeping things simple, the models have the following attributes:

```
User
    - id

Project
    - id
    - owner_id
    - is_published

ProjectMember
    - user_id
    - project_id
```

Using sequelize.js, I want to find all projects where the project owner is a specific user, or where there is a project member for that project whose user is that user, or where the project is published. I imagine the raw SQL would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM Project p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectMember m
    ON p.id = m.project_id
WHERE m.user_id = 2
    OR p.owner_id = 2
    OR p.is_published = true;
```

There are plenty of examples out there on how to perform a query on an association, but I can find none on how to do so conditionally. I have been able to query just the association using this code:

```js
projModel.findAll({
    where: { },
    include: [{
        model: memberModel,
        as: 'projectMembers',
        where: { 'user_id': 2 }
    }]
})
```

How do I combine this where query in an $or to check the project's owner_id and is_published columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's frustrating, I worked for hours to try to solve this problem, and as soon as I ask here I found a way to do it. As it turns out, sequelize.js developers recently added the ability to use raw keys in your where query, making it (at long last) possible to query an association inside of the main where clause.

This is my solution:

```js
projModel.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: {
            '$projectMembers.user_id$': 2,
            owner_id: 2,
            is_published: true
        }
    },
    include: [{
        model: memberModel,
        as: 'projectMembers'
    }]
})
```

Note: this solution breaks if you use 'limit' in the find options. As an alternative, you can fetch all results and then manually limit them afterwards.

Comment: this gives error and i know documentation say the same thing

Comment: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Customer is associated to Deal using an alias. You've included an alias (abc), but it does not match the alias defined in your association.`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It's impossible to know without more code, but it sounds like you might have defined your models incorrectly. Then again, I'm not an expert. Have you tried asking a question on SO?

Comment: for the record i had to find right alias using debugger... `Customer.associations....` defining with `as` had no effect... maybe if you define custom pass through table name in schema when defining association `as` tag doesn't work?